# What kind of accent is

Tags: accent

There is a video from someone on youtube. The voice is beautiful. I'm not a native English speaker, so I wonder if anyone could define his accent. It sounds like Scottish, like Sean Connery if I’m correct.

(a link)

Comment: _The Honest Guys_ have a UK website: [https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4jWo5kiyOCt4PnvF4jbaLg](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4jWo5kiyOCt4PnvF4jbaLg). I'd say a Brit/Aussie blend.

Comment: Yuk. Nauseating. Australian who has had voice lessons from Brits.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is spam for a prayer video.

Comment: @Michael Harvey: It IS very yucky. Yes - probably spam. Brit/Aussie or just piss-elegant Aussie? Hard to tell.

Comment: To me, it is 99% RP and 1% 'maybe antipodean', but you've got to be careful because a lot of Estuary speakers sound vaguely Australian these days; this has been noted [by linguists](https://language-and-innovation.com/2019/01/29/mockney-estuary-and-the-queens-english/)   (blog about Mockney and estuary - the author talks about 'the mysterious vowels of someone pretending not to be from Birmingham'). It is a learned accent. Nobody talks like that naturally.

Comment: if the piece had been delivered in Morningside Scots I might have listened a little longer.

Comment: Long-lost recordings unearthed in 2010 revealed that Queen Victoria had an unmistakeably German accent. Who knew?

Comment: Thank you for answers. It’s not a spam. You have offended me.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not Scottish.

At 1'13" the words "it's roots in fear, and so..." are clearly either Australian or New Zealand.

For me the giveaways are:

```
1'46" flow
2'14" because you
2'56" innocent
```

I would guess Australian, but we need someone from there (and I don't often say that!) to tell us which it is.